# C - Sort multiple arrays as one with generic function

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I need to sort multiple arrays as one with a generic function that gets parameters via ellipses.

I tried to put all the elements inside one array, sort it and then push the results into the following arrays.

This is the prototype of the function:

```
void gSortAll(int n, int m, int(*cmp)(void*,void*),void* base,...);
```

**int n**: The number of elements in each array.

**int m**: The size in bytes of each element in array.

**cmp**: compare function to compare between specific type.

**void* base**: the first array to sort, following other arrays with ellipses and then NULL.

Let's say I call the function with these arrays:

```
int a[] = {17,2,7,8,1};
int b[] = {3,6,5,14,11};
int c[] = {12,9,10,1,4};
```

After the sorting function the arrays should be:

```
int a[] = {1,1,2,3,4};
int b[] = {5,6,7,8,9};
int c[] = {10,11,12,14,17};
```

I've already started to type the function:

```
int cmpInt(void *a, void *b) {
    return *(int*)a > *(int*)b;
}

void swap(void* p, void* q, int size) { 
    char *pt = (char *)p;
    char *qt = (char *)q;
    char c;
    while(size--) {
        c = *pt;
        *pt = *qt;
        *qt = c;
        pt++;
        qt++;
    }
}

void insert(void* from, void* to, int size) { 
    char *pt = (char *)from;
    char *qt = (char *)to;
    while(size--) {
        *qt = *pt;
        pt++;
        qt++;
    }
}

void sort(void* arr, int size, int sizeType, int(*f)(void *, void *)) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<size-1; j++) {
            if(f((char*)arr+j*sizeType,(char*)arr+j*sizeType+sizeType)>0) {
                swap((char*)arr+j*sizeType,(char*)arr+j*sizeType+sizeType, sizeType);
            }
        }
    }
}

// n: number of elements in array
// m: size in bytes of element
// cmp: compare function
// base: the first array
void gSortAll(int n, int m, int(*cmp)(void*,void*),void* base,...) {
    void** arr = malloc(0);
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    void* item;
    va_list param;
    va_start(param, base);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        arr = realloc(arr, m*(count+1));
        arr[count] = (char*)base+i*m;
        count++;
    }
    va_start(param, base);
    while((item=va_arg(param, void*))!=NULL) {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            arr = realloc(arr, m*(count+1));
            arr[count] = (char*)item+i*m;
            count++;
        }
    }
    va_end(param);
    sort(arr, count, m, cmp);
    va_start(param, base);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) insert(arr+i*m, base+i*m, m);
    va_start(param, base);
    while((item=va_arg(param, void*))!=NULL) {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) insert(arr+i*m, item+i*m, m);
    }
    va_end(param);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {17,2,7,8,1};
    int b[] = {3,6,5,14,11};
    int c[] = {12,9,10,1,4};
    gSortAll(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), *cmpInt, a, b, c, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What _exactly_ is your question?

Comment: @myradio the function gSortAll is not working and I want to fix it. All the other functions are working.

Comment: What do you mean by _it is not working?_ giving an error? result different than expected? We are likely to get much more feedback if you make it more specific.

Comment: @myradio I have a with malloc that I try to access block of memory after it was freed, and the pushing of elements back to the arrays in the Ellipsis isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `sort` code (and some but not all the supporting functions) verbatim, here is a variation on `gSortAll()` with a slightly different signature.  It avoids the explicit `void *base` argument so that doesn't have to be treated specially.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void sort(void *arr, int size, int sizeType, int (*f)(void *, void *));

/* Changed (simplified) function signature */
static void gSortAll(int n, int m, int (*cmp)(void *, void *), ...)
{
    void *item;
    va_list param;

    /* How many arrays? */
    va_start(param, cmp);
    size_t num_arrays = 0;
    while ((item = va_arg(param, void *)) != 0)
        num_arrays++;
    va_end(param);

    if (num_arrays == 0)
        return;

    void *arr = malloc(num_arrays * n * m);
    if (arr == 0)
        return;

    /* Copy data into allocated array */
    va_start(param, cmp);
    void *data = arr;
    while ((item = va_arg(param, void *)) != 0)
    {
        memmove(data, item, n * m);
        data = (char *)data + n * m;
    }
    va_end(param);

    sort(arr, n * num_arrays, m, cmp);

    /* Copy data from allocated array */
    va_start(param, cmp);
    data = arr;
    while ((item = va_arg(param, void *)))
    {
        memmove(item, data, n * m);
        data = (char *)data + n * m;
    }
    va_end(param);

    free(arr);
}

static int cmpInt(void *a, void *b)
{
    return *(int *)a > *(int *)b;
}

static void swap(void *p, void *q, int size)
{
    char *pt = (char *)p;
    char *qt = (char *)q;
    char c;
    while (size--)
    {
        c = *pt;
        *pt = *qt;
        *qt = c;
        pt++;
        qt++;
    }
}

static void sort(void *arr, int size, int sizeType, int (*f)(void *, void *))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (f((char *)arr + j * sizeType, (char *)arr + j * sizeType + sizeType) > 0)
            {
                swap((char *)arr + j * sizeType, (char *)arr + j * sizeType + sizeType,
                     sizeType);
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Non-generic code */
static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t size, int data[size])
{
    printf("%s (%zu):  ", tag, size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%5d", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {17, 2, 7, 8, 1};
    int b[] = {3, 6, 5, 14, 11};
    int c[] = {12, 9, 10, 1, 4};

    printf("Before\n");
    dump_array("A", 5, a);
    dump_array("B", 5, b);
    dump_array("C", 5, c);

    gSortAll(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), *cmpInt,
             (void *)a, (void *)b, (void *)c, (void *)NULL);

    printf("After\n");
    dump_array("A", 5, a);
    dump_array("B", 5, b);
    dump_array("C", 5, c);

    /* random -n 12 10 99 | commalist -B 4 -w -W3 -n 12 -b 'int w[] = { ' -T ' };' */
    int w[] = {  86,  86,  48,  40,  39,  29,  69,  71,  30,  15,  46,  19, };
    int x[] = {  21,  43,  11,  85,  82,  81,  41,  46,  33,  32,  15,  43, };
    int y[] = {  91,  19,  82,  33,  25,  83,  36,  85,  75,  65,  37,  57, };
    int z[] = {  39,  61,  65,  83,  26,  82,  30,  81,  30,  34,  22,  82, };

    printf("Before\n");
    dump_array("W", 12, w);
    dump_array("X", 12, x);
    dump_array("Y", 12, y);
    dump_array("Z", 12, z);

    gSortAll(sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]), sizeof(w[0]), *cmpInt,
             (void *)w, (void *)x, (void *)y, (void *)z, (void *)NULL);

    printf("After\n");
    dump_array("W", 12, w);
    dump_array("X", 12, x);
    dump_array("Y", 12, y);
    dump_array("Z", 12, z);

    return 0;
}
```

It uses `memmove()` — you can use `memcpy()` if you prefer — to copy the separate arrays into the single array it creates, and to copy the sorted data back out to the separate arrays.

Sample output:

```
Before
A (5):     17    2    7    8    1
B (5):      3    6    5   14   11
C (5):     12    9   10    1    4
After
A (5):      1    1    2    3    4
B (5):      5    6    7    8    9
C (5):     10   11   12   14   17
Before
W (12):     86   86   48   40   39   29   69   71   30   15   46   19
X (12):     21   43   11   85   82   81   41   46   33   32   15   43
Y (12):     91   19   82   33   25   83   36   85   75   65   37   57
Z (12):     39   61   65   83   26   82   30   81   30   34   22   82
After
W (12):     11   15   15   19   19   21   22   25   26   29   30   30
X (12):     30   32   33   33   34   36   37   39   39   40   41   43
Y (12):     43   46   46   48   57   61   65   65   69   71   75   81
Z (12):     81   82   82   82   82   83   83   85   85   86   86   91
```

Runs with a clean bill of health from Valgrind.

If you absolutely must have the `void *base` argument, then you have to process that separately inside the code, which is silly as the named argument provides no benefit to the user of the function and imposes some cost on the implementation.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void sort(void *arr, int size, int sizeType, int (*f)(void *, void *));

/* Changed (simplified) function signature */
static void gSortAll(int n, int m, int (*cmp)(void *, void *), void *base, ...)
{
    void *item;
    va_list param;

    if (base == 0)
        return;

    /* How many arrays? */
    va_start(param, base);
    size_t num_arrays = 1;      // base is counted too
    while ((item = va_arg(param, void *)) != 0)
        num_arrays++;
    va_end(param);

    void *arr = malloc(num_arrays * n * m);
    if (arr == 0)
        return;

    /* Copy data into allocated array */
    void *data = arr;
    memmove(data, base, n * m);
    data = (char *)data + n * m;
    va_start(param, base);
    while ((item = va_arg(param, void *)) != 0)
    {
        memmove(data, item, n * m);
        data = (char *)data + n * m;
    }
    va_end(param);

    sort(arr, n * num_arrays, m, cmp);

    /* Copy data from allocated array */
    data = arr;
    memmove(base, data, n * m);
    data = (char *)data + n * m;
    va_start(param, base);
    while ((item = va_arg(param, void *)))
    {
        memmove(item, data, n * m);
        data = (char *)data + n * m;
    }
    va_end(param);

    free(arr);
}

static int cmpInt(void *a, void *b)
{
    return *(int *)a > *(int *)b;
}

static void swap(void *p, void *q, int size)
{
    char *pt = (char *)p;
    char *qt = (char *)q;
    char c;
    while (size--)
    {
        c = *pt;
        *pt = *qt;
        *qt = c;
        pt++;
        qt++;
    }
}

static void sort(void *arr, int size, int sizeType, int (*f)(void *, void *))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (f((char *)arr + j * sizeType, (char *)arr + j * sizeType + sizeType) > 0)
            {
                swap((char *)arr + j * sizeType, (char *)arr + j * sizeType + sizeType,
                     sizeType);
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Non-generic code */
static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t size, int data[size])
{
    printf("%s (%zu):  ", tag, size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%5d", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {17, 2, 7, 8, 1};
    int b[] = {3, 6, 5, 14, 11};
    int c[] = {12, 9, 10, 1, 4};

    printf("Before\n");
    dump_array("A", 5, a);
    dump_array("B", 5, b);
    dump_array("C", 5, c);

    gSortAll(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), *cmpInt,
             (void *)a, (void *)b, (void *)c, (void *)NULL);

    printf("After\n");
    dump_array("A", 5, a);
    dump_array("B", 5, b);
    dump_array("C", 5, c);

    /* random -n 12 10 99 | commalist -B 4 -w -W3 -n 12 -b 'int w[] = { ' -T ' };' */
    int w[] = {  86,  86,  48,  40,  39,  29,  69,  71,  30,  15,  46,  19, };
    int x[] = {  21,  43,  11,  85,  82,  81,  41,  46,  33,  32,  15,  43, };
    int y[] = {  91,  19,  82,  33,  25,  83,  36,  85,  75,  65,  37,  57, };
    int z[] = {  39,  61,  65,  83,  26,  82,  30,  81,  30,  34,  22,  82, };

    printf("Before\n");
    dump_array("W", 12, w);
    dump_array("X", 12, x);
    dump_array("Y", 12, y);
    dump_array("Z", 12, z);

    gSortAll(sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]), sizeof(w[0]), *cmpInt,
             (void *)w, (void *)x, (void *)y, (void *)z, (void *)NULL);

    printf("After\n");
    dump_array("W", 12, w);
    dump_array("X", 12, x);
    dump_array("Y", 12, y);
    dump_array("Z", 12, z);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is the same as before.

<sup>*There was a [previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51013921/15168) (10K users only) which ended up being both confusing and deleted (but it was submitted by a different user ID).  This is an extension of one of the two answers I wrote for that question — two being necessary because of the confusion.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to convince yourself that every piece of your code is actually needed and does what it's meant to.  It would also help to sub-divide your code into slightly smaller meaningful primitives that you can test and debug in isolation.

Hints:

- it's possible to pre-allocate the temporary space once
- `insert()` can help with the gather-copy step just like it does with the scatter-copy
- there are library functions to do the job for `insert()` and `sort()`

Answer (score 1):

There must be `va_end()` pair for each `va_start()`.

In your `gSortAll()` function, you start a new `va_start()` block, before the previous was ended with `va_end()`:

```
va_start(param, base);
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    arr = realloc(arr, m*(count+1));
    arr[count] = (char*)base+i*m;
    count++;
}
va_start(param, base);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without ever calling *alloc functions. What you need is:

- a custom container, which can iterate over specified num of arrays with specified number of elements, where pointers to those arrays are stored in a `va_list` "object".
- custom quicksort function, that will use that container to access array elements

I have written a container `arrs`, which is initialized with number of arrays, number of elements in each array, size of an array member and a pointer va_list to the first array.
Then I used the some quicksort function which I found on the net (used one from [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/02/quicksort-program-in-c/)) and rewritten it, so that whenever it calls `arr[n]` it calls my container member access function.
Full code is here:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/* arrs_s --------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * arrs_s structure holds numOfArrays arrays each with numOfElemsInArrays of size size
 * starting in variable argument list va
 */
struct arrs_s {
    size_t numOfArrays;
    size_t numOfElemsInArrays;
    size_t membSize;
    va_list va;
};
/**
 * Intializes arrs_s object
 */
void arrs_init(struct arrs_s *t, size_t numOfArrays, size_t numOfElemsInArrays, size_t membSize, va_list va)
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    assert(membSize != 0);
#ifndef NDEBUG
    // assert all arrays in va_list are not NULL
    va_list va2;
    va_copy(va2, va);
    for (size_t i = numOfArrays; i; --i) {
        assert(va_arg(va2, void*) != NULL);
    }
    va_end(va2);
#endif

    t->numOfArrays = numOfArrays;
    t->numOfElemsInArrays = numOfElemsInArrays;
    t->membSize = membSize;
    va_copy(t->va, va);

}
/**
 * Bassically calls va_end
 */
void arrs_fini(struct arrs_s *t)
{
    va_end(t->va);
}
/**
 * Gets the pointer to element number pos
 */
void *arrs_get(struct arrs_s *t, size_t pos)
{
    assert(pos < t->numOfArrays * t->numOfElemsInArrays);
    size_t n = pos/t->numOfElemsInArrays;
    const size_t m = pos%t->numOfElemsInArrays;

    // get n element in a va list
    va_list va;
    va_copy(va, t->va);
    void *ret;
    while (n--) {
        ret = va_arg(va, void*);
    }
    ret = va_arg(va, void*);
    va_end(va);

    assert(ret != NULL);
    return (void*)(&((char*)ret)[t->membSize * m]);
}
/**
 * Get single element size, maybe should be refactored to arrs_membsize...
 */
size_t arrs_size(struct arrs_s *t)
{
    return t->membSize;
}

/* qsort --------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * Swap size bytes of memory between a and b
 */
static inline
void gSortAll_swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
#if 1 || C99_VLA
    char tmp[size];
    memcpy(tmp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, size);
#else
    char c;
    char *ca = a;
    char *cb = b;
    while (size--) {
        c = *ca;
        *ca++ = *cb;
        *cb++ = c;
    }
#endif
}

// rewritten from from https://beginnersbook.com/2015/02/quicksort-program-in-c/
static
void qSortAll_in(struct arrs_s *t, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *),
            size_t first, size_t last)
{
   if (first < last){
      void * const pivot = arrs_get(t, first);
      size_t i = first;
      size_t j = last;

      while (i < j) {
          while (cmp(arrs_get(t, i), pivot) <= 0 && i < last) {
              ++i;
          }
          while (cmp(arrs_get(t, j), pivot) > 0) {
              j--;
          }
          if (i < j) {
              gSortAll_swap(arrs_get(t, i), arrs_get(t, j), arrs_size(t));
          }
      }
      gSortAll_swap(arrs_get(t, j), pivot, arrs_size(t));

      if (j > 0) {
          qSortAll_in(t, cmp, first, j - 1);
      }
      assert(j != SIZE_MAX);
      qSortAll_in(t, cmp, j + 1, last);
   }
}

void qSortAll(size_t numOfArrays, size_t numOfElemsInArrays,
        size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void *), /*void *base,*/ ...)
{
    assert(cmp != NULL);

    if (numOfArrays == 0 || numOfElemsInArrays == 0)
        return;

    va_list va;
    struct arrs_s t;

    va_start(va, cmp);
    arrs_init(&t, numOfArrays, numOfElemsInArrays, size, va);

    qSortAll_in(&t, cmp, 0, numOfArrays * numOfElemsInArrays - 1);

    arrs_fini(&t);
    va_end(va);
}

/* main -------------------------------------------------------------- */

void printarr(int *a, size_t s)
{
    printf(" %p[%zu] = ", a, s);
    while (s--) {
        printf("%d,", *a++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int ia = *(int*)a;
    const int ib = *(int*)b;
    return ia == ib ? 0 : ia < ib ? -1 : 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {17,2,7,8,1};
    int b[] = {3,6,5,14,11};
    int c[] = {12,9,10,1,4};

#if 0 || TEST
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i) {
        a[i] = rand()&0xff;
        b[i] = rand()&0xff;
        c[i] = rand()&0xff;
    }
#endif

    printf("Unsorted:\n");
    printarr(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    printarr(b, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
    printarr(c, sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]));
    printf("\n");

    qSortAll(3, 5, sizeof(int), cmp, a, b, c);

    printf("Sorted:\n");
    printarr(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    printarr(b, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
    printarr(c, sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]));
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Unsorted:
 0x1fff000360[5] = 17,2,7,8,1,
 0x1fff000380[5] = 3,6,5,14,11,
 0x1fff0003a0[5] = 12,9,10,1,4,

Sorted:
 0x1fff000360[5] = 1,1,2,3,4,
 0x1fff000380[5] = 5,6,7,8,9,
 0x1fff0003a0[5] = 10,11,12,14,17,
```

Comment: Note the rules in [C11 §7.15.1 Variable argument list access macros](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.15.1), where it says: _Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros
shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function._  Your code with `arrs_fini()` does not meet this rule.  You may actually get away with it, especially if `va_end()` is a no-op on your platform, but it is not meeting the letter of the standard and hence is not reliably portable.

Comment: Thank You! I didn't know it has to be *in the same function*, so this code is bad, as it relates on *undefined behavior* (see J.2.). Unless you rewrite it as macros only. Surprisingly it works in https://www.onlinegdb.com , but one shouldn't rely on it. Thanks.